# Undefined index with PDO code

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Trying to insert data into a table with the following code :

```
if ($valid) {
            $pdo = Database::connect();
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO customers (FName, LName, JAddress, BAddress, Phone, APhone, Email, AEmail) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($FName,$LName,$JAddress,$Baddress,$Phone,$APhone,$Email,$AEmail,$id));
            Database::disconnect();
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
```

values

```
// keep track post values
        $id       = $POST['id'];
        $FName    = $_POST['FName'];
        .....etc
```

form

```
<div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($nameError)?'error':'';?>">
                        <label class="control-label">ID</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input name="id" type="text"  placeholder="ID" value="<?php echo !empty($id)?$id:'';?>">
                            <?php if (!id($idError)): ?>
                                <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $idError;?></span>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($FNameError)?'error':'';?>">
                        <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input name="FName" type="text"  placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo !empty($FName)?$FName:'';?>">
                            <?php if (!empty($FNameError)): ?>
                                <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $FNameError;?></span>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

I get to a page that shows the ID form field, which I wanted to keep hidden, and have it of course auto increment.  Below the form field I get :
Call to undefined function id()

If I put in an ID # and press enter I get the following errors :
Notice: Undefined variable: POST
Notice: Undefined index: Phone
...etc

I know this has to be some fumble key on my part, but am not spotting it.  Does anyone see where I went wrong?

Comment: there are post elements for 8 values, did not show all to condense question

Comment: You have your answer below, with an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `$id = $POST['id'];`

```
$POST
```

Is missing an underscore:

```
$_POST
```

It's a superglobal http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

- Which explains the notice.

**Nota:** You also have an extra argument `$id` in

```
((array($FName,$LName,$JAddress,$Baddress,$Phone,$APhone,$Email,$AEmail,$id))
```

which may also pose a problem.

Comment: i altered this from having three values to eight, with three it worked just fine.  I do not want to do anything with the $id variable

Comment: @Steven Ok, I had to mention that, just in case.

Comment: @Steven So, question's been solved? Where are we at?

Comment: just got done testing again- the extra $id caused the issue, thanks!

Comment: @Steven You're welcome Steven, *cheers!* Glad to know it's been resolved.

Comment: Its amazing how such a small error can break the whole thing

Comment: @Steven I know the feeling. I once spent 45 minutes trying to find what was wrong in code years ago, only to be a stray dot. Yep, been there! Funny what one character will do.

Comment: ha, been there as well, no problems with dots yet,  have missed "}"s though

Comment: fixed that with a good notepad, used to just use microsofts, but switched to notepad++

Comment: @Steven I used to code in Windows Notepad years ago, till I found Notepad++, it's good for matching brackets/braces, but not so good for matching quotes, which is a downside to it. Programs like Aptana, and Titanium Studio do. There are others too.

Comment: aptana looks awesome, I will have to give it a try!  Thanks!